# Page numbering doesn't work

Tags: page-numbering

Hello dear LaTeX community, I have a problem with page numbering. Namely, the numbering of the "Acknowledgments" chapter is not displayed. The Roman numbering only starts from the "Abstract". Can anyone help me on this?

```
\documentclass[ egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
                a4paper,
                final,
                12pt, 
                %twosides %For printing
                oneside
                ]{scrbook}

%Insert your personal data to update the whole document
\newcommand{\myName}{LA}
\newcommand{\myStudentID}{XXXXXX}
\newcommand{\myPlace}{DO}
\newcommand{\myThesis}{Thesis}
\newcommand{\myHochschule}{University}
%\newcommand{\myCompany}{-}
\newcommand{\myUniversitySupervisor}{MK}
%\newcommand{\myTechnicalSupervisor}{-}



\input{auxfiles/doc_config}

%----------------------------------------Preamble------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%Title page
\input{auxfiles/cover}

%----------------------------------------Formatter------------------------------------
\pagenumbering{Roman}                   %Roman page numbering for Formatter

%\setcounter{page}{2}
%\input{auxfiles/sperrvermerk}

\input{auxfiles/acknowledgements}

\input{chapters/0_abstract}

\newpage
%\phantomsection
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{plain}%\fancyhead[L]{CONTENTS}

\phantomsection
%\setcounter{page}{10}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures\thispagestyle{plain}

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables\thispagestyle{plain}

%\newpage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}
%\lstlistoflistings.

%Import acronyms
\input{auxfiles/acronyms}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]\thispagestyle{plain}

%----------------------------------------Mainmatter------------------------------------
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}                  %Arabic numbering for mainmatter
%Content

\input{chapters/1_introduction}
\input{chapters/2_background}
\input{chapters/3_setup}
\input{chapters/4_methods}
\input{chapters/5_results}
\input{chapters/6_conclusions}
\input{chapters/7_outlook}

%----------------------------------------Endmatter------------------------------------
\newpage

%\pagenumbering{Roman}                   %Roman page numbering for Endmatter

\appendix

\input{chapters/99_appendix}

%Bibliography
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}

%Confirmation of honesty
\input{auxfiles/honor}


\end{document}
```

doc_config

```
%-------------------------------------Packages-------------------------------------
% Language setting
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,
            top = 2cm, 
            bottom = 2cm, 
            left = 4cm, 
            includehead, 
            includefoot, 
            right = 2cm]{geometry}

%Set headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}                                  %Clear all footers and headers
%\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}                    %Gives the chapter name

%\fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[width = 0.15\textwidth]{Siemens-logo.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}


\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}                         %Create dummy text
\usepackage{setspace}                       %Give bigger spacing in between the lines of the title
%\usepackage{tocbibind}                      %Add list of figures and list of tables to the toc
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}            %Enable hyperlinks to jump to different sections
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc, acronym, nonumberlist, style = super]{glossaries}       %Use acronyms and create a section that shows the acronym and its meaning
\usepackage{chngcntr}                       %Change how figures are numbered
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}                       %Prettier tables
\usepackage{caption}                        
\usepackage{subcaption}                     %Allows subfigures
\usepackage{listings}                       %Create blocks of code
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}

\MakeOuterQuote{"}


\newboolean{draftBool}
\setboolean{draftBool}{false}
%Draft Watermark
\ifdraftBool
    \usepackage{background}
    \backgroundsetup{contents={DRAFT},color={red},opacity = {0.1}}
\fi

\newboolean{dS}
\setboolean{dS}{false}
\ifdS
    \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\textit{\rightmark}}                   %Gives the section name
    %\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\myName{}}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\else
    \fancyhead[L]{\textit{\rightmark}}                   %Gives the section name
    %\fancyhead[R]{\myName{}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fi



\input{auxfiles/code_listings}             %Defining SCL as a programming language for use in listing


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                 %No indentation in new paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}                   %Distance between paragraphs = 6pt
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}        %Line spacing = 1.3

%\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}            %Change figure numbering to sequential order (1,2,...,n)
%\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\makeglossaries

\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\def\code#1{\textit{\texttt{#1}}}                    %Define a command to write monospace text in form of a code

%Define Pagestyles
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    %\fancyhead[R]{\myName{}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
```

Comment: This is not a minimal working example which would make it hard for other people to find your issue. We cannot compile your code because we don't have all the files you `\input` in your document.

Comment: put a \newpage before the \pagenumbering{Roman}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've already tried that, unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Comment: well then make a better example, so that we don't have to guess what you have in your files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I uploaded the doc_config. Does that help you? The chapters only have \chapter*{}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ?

Comment: Your issue is about the Acknowledgements section but we cannot see what's in the `auxfiles/acknowledgements.tex` file. If we cannot compile your code we cannot help you. You should remove all the `\input` commands except the ones necessary to create the problem, and all other extraneous code. See this post on creating a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: The acknowledgment section only contains the following: \chapter*{Acknowledgment}

Comment: @frabjous I'm sorry if I make this unnecessarily difficult for you. Unfortunately I'm a beginner and only used a template.

Comment: If the files you `\input` only contain one or two macros, then you can just replace the `\input` macros in your MWE by the contents of these files. If you are sure that these lines are not relevant to the problem, you should not include them in your MWE, however. Try to make your MWE as short as possible but as large as needed to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: If I take your code, and comment out all the `\input` commands, except `auxfiles/doc_config` which you provided, and replace the one for `auxfiles/acknowledgements.tex` with just `\chapter*{Acknowledgments}`, then I get a page number on the Acknowlegements page. Make a copy of your project and try that yourself: do you get a page number? If you do, then it must be something in one of those included files that is responsible; restore them until the problem comes back. If you don't, then post your `.log` file. That's all I can suggest unless you make a MWE.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to insert a blank page and then remove it in the pdf. Then it will work. Nevertheless thank you for your help.